# Unable to connect even after changing the values

Tags: magento-1.7

I have downloaded a copy of my website and changed the local.xml, username, password and db value to my mamp local, which is localhost, root, root. Deleted my contents in var folder but still i get ,

**There has been an error processing your request**

i tracedback the error shown under var/report/..... and it says,*a:4:{i:0;s:87:"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '[root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:2652:"#0 * , my other websites on localhost connect with same credentials really well. what else should i look for to debug and make things working??

Comment: make sure you don't have an extra space in your username or password.

Comment: @Marius there isn't any

Comment: Looks like you have a left bracket before root.

Comment: @Dan it worked. yay!

Comment: Great, I'll make it an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the left bracket in front of root. Marius pointed to a simple answer, which led me to look for one as well.